# Mac OSX forward internet sharing through VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, bridge

I have been trying to forward packets from my internet sharing interface (bridge100) to my tunnel interface (VPN Software creates utun2) using the following:

```
nat pass on utun2 from bridge100:network to any -> (utun2)
```

But when I get my global IP in the machine connected to bridge100 I still get my regular WAN IP, not my VPN public IP. My current setup is:

[image: Setup]

And I want packets from the device connected to bridge100 (screen with 192.168.2.6) to also go through the VPN.

Is there any way to accomplish this using `pfctl` or anything else?

Cheers,